# Adding repository to Eclipse using Subclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

I have created a repository on Unix server and trying to connect it using Subclipse on my local machine. When I try to add a repository in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
RA layer request failed
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://XXX/<my repository>': 200 OK (https://XXX)
```

I am using Subclipse as a plugin. on Windows XP machine. Is there any way I can check locally that the repository is accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with TortoiseSVN it is more descriptive in its errors, you can check the parameters with its repobrowser.

Anyway that doesn´t seem an error, return 200 it is an ok reponse, so probably what it is returning it is not ok for Subclipse, probably it is the url that is missing some information.